# Adding milliseconds to a table where there is duplicate datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a temp table, I'm not sure if that matters, it is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ActivityLog 
(
     ActivityLogID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     VehicleID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     ActivityDateTime DATETIME
)
```

I am trying to manipulate the table so that I don't have any `ActivityDateTime` duplicated per `VehicleID`.

With this query, I am getting my duplicated values.

```
SELECT
    s.ActivityLogID, t.* 
FROM
    #ActivityLog s 
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         VehicleID, ActivityDateTime, COUNT(*) AS qty
     FROM 
         #ActivityLog
     GROUP BY 
         VehicleID, ActivityDateTime
     HAVING
         COUNT(*) > 1) t ON s.VehicleID = t.VehicleID 
                         AND s.ActivityDateTime = t.ActivityDateTime 
ORDER BY
    t.qty DESC
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to loop through them to be able to add 3 milliseconds (least time handled by SQL) when duplicates are found.

So if I have some rows like the following (I will simplify the uniqueID's so they display easier)

```
ActivityLogID  |      VehicleID  |     ActivityDateTime     
---------------+-----------------+--------------------------
     1                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     2                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     3                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     4                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     5                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     6                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     7                     9         2019-06-03 18:49:53.000    
     8                     9         2019-06-03 18:50:53.000    
     9                     9         2019-06-03 18:50:53.000    
     10                    9         2019-06-03 18:51:53.000    
     11                    9         2019-06-03 18:51:53.000    
     12                    9         2019-06-03 18:52:53.000
```

The output should look like

```
ActivityLogID  |      VehicleID  |     ActivityDateTime     
---------------+-----------------+--------------------------
     1                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.000    
     2                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.003    
     3                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.006    
     4                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.009    
     5                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.012    
     6                     9         2019-06-03 18:48:53.015    
     7                     9         2019-06-03 18:49:53.018    
     8                     9         2019-06-03 18:50:53.000    
     9                     9         2019-06-03 18:50:53.003    
     10                    9         2019-06-03 18:51:53.000    
     11                    9         2019-06-03 18:51:53.003    
     12                    9         2019-06-03 18:52:53.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the data sounds like a bad idea.  I would add 5 milliseconds just to be safe using `row_number()`.  So:

```
Select s.*,
       dateadd(millisecond,
               (row_number() over (partition by VehicleID, ActivityDateTime order by (select null)) - 1) * 5,
               ActivityDateTime
              ) as munged_ActivityDateTime
from #ActivityLog s
order by t.qty desc
```

Comment: why does it sound as bad idea? can you elaborate a bit? this is being worked on a temp table

Comment: @pato.llaguno . . . Changing internal data to enforce such uniqueness is a bad idea.  Why can't you just use `ActivityLogId` if you want a unique key?

Comment: i need datetime to be unique becuase of some scripts used to calculate times in between rows, but i wouldn't be changing data, just in a temp table

Comment: I did make this work with this code, when i insert to the temp table i use the row_number() the only thing is that i am still getting some duplicate, much less almost neglectable but yet there are some, do you happen to know why?

Comment: @pato.llaguno . . . Are you using 5 milliseconds or 3?  With 3 you can definitely get duplicates.

Comment: I'm using 5, I just figured out what's happening, the duplicates is because for some reason the value is already taken by another row that was not duplicated in the first place

Comment: @pato.llaguno . . . 6 or 7 would further reduce the chance of such duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using the technique Gordon suggests, in a CTE, you can update the table. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT *, 
 row_number() over (partition by VehicleID, ActivityDateTime order by (select null)) as rownum
 from #ActivityLog
)
UPDATE CTE SET ActivityDateTime = DATEADD(millisecond,(rownum-1)*3, ActivityDateTime)
WHERE rownum>1;
```

And may I also suggest, if you don't want dublicates for VehicleID and ActivityDateTime, create a unique constraint on the table.

Comment: where is the table #ActivityLog referenced? should i place it before the where?

Comment: My bad. It should be inside the CTE definition. I'm updating my answer.